# nginx as reverse proxy in front of Liferay portal server

Tags: nginx, proxy, liferay

I've already read a lot of questions and answers here about nginx configuration, but none of the shown configurations worked for me. I need to configure nginx to act as a reverse proxy in front of a Liferay portal server, running on port 8080. The Liferay portal hosts several websites, which are accessible as "virtual hosts" under distinct URL's, like "firstsite.myserver.com" and "secondsite.myserver.com".
Therefore requests from the reverse proxy must keep the url from the original request, and just change the port from 80 to 8080.

My Problem: Whatever I try the requests reach my Liferay server with just the localhost IP 127.0.0.1 instead of the complete URL, and all "internal" Links in the server are generated with 127.0.0.1 instead of the domain names. It would be sufficient to have a working configuration for just one website, then I could build up the others later in a similar way.

This is a snippet from one of my tries of a proxy configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  firstsite.myserver.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://firstsite.myserver.com:8080/;  
    }
```

Also tried things like that:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  secondsite.myserver.com;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://secondsite.myserver.com:8080;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_redirect http://$host:8080/ http://$host/;

    }
```

To be honest, I can't figure out where and how the $host variable, used in the example above, is set. I'm on Windows platform b.t.w. Any help would be greatly appreciated, on how to configure nging to simple route "http://firstsite.myserver.com" to "http://firstsite.myserver.com:8080" forth and back through the reverse proxy.

Comment: have you set the host of site in the site settings to http://firstsite.myserver.com?

Comment: Do you mean the virtual host settings in Liferay? Yes, I've set the virtual host settings in both sites, and also removed the web.server.host property from portal-ext.properties, as this only works as long as the portal server only hosts one domain.